# How to avoid infinite loop in UseEffect from dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to fetch data from firebase on mount but also on new state changes(when user adds new todo), it is a Todo app that I'm trying to practice and learn. Tried useCallbacks and checked some other posts but couldn't handle it, thanks!

`

```
import React from 'react';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const initialTodos = [];

const TodoContext = React.createContext({
    todos: [],
    onTodoSubmit: () => {},
    onRemoveTodo: () => {},
    fetcher:  () => {},
});

export const TodoContextProvider = (props) => {

    const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState(initialTodos);

    const [ isInputEmpty, setIsInputEmpty] = useState();

    const fetcher = async () => {
        
        const response = await fetch('API INFO/todos.json');
        const data = await response.json();

        const loadedTodos = [];

        for (const key in data) {
            loadedTodos.push({
                id: key,
                todo: data[key].todo.todo,
                color: data[key].todo.color
            })
        }
        setTodos(loadedTodos)
        };

    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetcher()
    }, [todos])

    
    
    const onTodoSubmitHandler = async (userInput) => {
        
        fetch('API INFO', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                todo: userInput
            })
        })

        // setTodos(prev => {
        //     return [...prev, userInput]
        // })
      };

    
    const onRemoveTodo = (id) => {

        fetch(`API INFO/${id}.json`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        // setTodos((prev) => {
        //     return prev.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)
        // })
    };
    
    const contextValue = {
        todos,
        addTodo: onTodoSubmitHandler,
        removeTodo: onRemoveTodo,
        fetchData: fetcher,
        setIsInputEmpty,
        isInputEmpty
    };


    

      
   return <TodoContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{props.children}</TodoContext.Provider>
}


export default TodoContext;
```

`

todos causes infinite loop, I checked some other posts and tried to use useCallback but couldn't handle it.

Comment: So, when the component (provider) is rendered, you're running the effect. In the effect, you're calling the `fetcher` function. In the `fetcher` function, you're changing the state of `todos`. Because the effect activates on changes to `todos`, the effect runs again. You get the point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `useEffect` is both setting `todos` and listening for changes in `todos`, which might be causing an infinite loop.

The effect does not seems to be dependent on the value of `todos`, so perhaps try remove it from the dependency array to prevent the loop. If some effects need to trigger when `todos` changes, a second `useEffect` could be added which only listens to changes in `todos`, but not to set it.

On the other hand, it seems that `fetcher` can be moved inside `useEffect`, so that it also does not need to be added to the dependency array.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetcher = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("API INFO/todos.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    const loadedTodos = [];

    for (const key in data) {
      loadedTodos.push({
        id: key,
        todo: data[key].todo.todo,
        color: data[key].todo.color,
      });
    }
    setTodos(loadedTodos);
  };

  fetcher();
}, []);
```

Alternatively, perhaps try wrap `fetcher` in a `useCallback`:

```
import { useCallback } from "react";

const fetcher = useCallback(async () => {
  const response = await fetch("API INFO/todos.json");
  const data = await response.json();
  const loadedTodos = [];

  for (const key in data) {
    loadedTodos.push({
      id: key,
      todo: data[key].todo.todo,
      color: data[key].todo.color,
    });
  }
  setTodos(loadedTodos);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  fetcher();
}, [fetcher]);
```

Also it seems that the commented out `setTodos` should be resumed in both events:

```
const onTodoSubmitHandler = async (userInput) => {
  fetch("API INFO", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      todo: userInput,
    }),
  });
  setTodos((prev) => {
    return [...prev, userInput];
  });
};
```

```
const onRemoveTodo = (id) => {
  fetch(`API INFO/${id}.json`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  setTodos((prev) => {
    return prev.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I actually tried this approach before post here but how can i provide fetcher function to context provider while the function in useEffect?

Comment: @Onur Perhaps try wrap `fetcher` in  `useCallback` when defining outside of `useEffect`, or simply define another function for the context to avoid changes to trigger `useEffect`.